# Nginx unknown directive "if($http_user_agent"

Tags: nginx

I try to return 503 status code when the user agent header has a specific value. I tried outside and inside the location block. But when I reload the this config nginx failes to reload:

```
upstream api{
    server 127.0.0.1:1336;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name api.project.com;

   # if($http_user_agent = "android") {
   #     return 503;
   # }

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    location / {

     # if($http_user_agent = "android") {
     #   return 503;
     # }

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://api/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Any ideas whats wrong? I am using nginx/1.4.7

From syslog:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($http_user_agent"
```

Comment: what's the nginx error message?

Comment: @John I just get Reloading nginx configuration (via systemctl): nginx.serviceJob failed. Can I find more specific error message somewhere else?

Comment: Well the logs are usually in /var/log/nginx/. Please also check if the port is already in use using 
`netstat -tupln`

Comment: @John of course, the port is in use. Nevertheless it should reload the config?!

Comment: Nevermind.. I read "restarting" ;) Anyway, I just loaded the config above and nginx is starting up without any problems so there's just your error log left. The path to it should be in your nginx.conf btw

Comment: @John I got the error in /var/log/syslog: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($http_user_agent"

Comment: If you've copied this from web, check for nonbreakable spaces and other funny characters

Comment: huh, add a space between `if` and `(`. that should do the trick!

Comment: @John that's the trick, a bit weird but it works. Make this the answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a space between if and (. that should do the trick!